# xcode 5.1 inline assembly

Tags: xcode, inline-assembly

I am struggling with putting a piece of inline assembly code into my xcode function. What I need to do is to rewrite this old little piece of code written in C++. Could anybody please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

```
unsigned long myFunction(void)
{
  static unsigned long rnd=0x4159c49;
  unsigned char y; 
  __asm
  {
    rdtsc;
    mov [y], al;
  }

  //some other operations
  return (rnd);
}
```

I tried to search for inline assembly in xcode, but couldn't really find anything relevant.
I tried to use inline assembly following way, but it gives me error expecting register:

```
__asm__(
    "rdtsc"
    "mov [y], al"
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet gets the full 64 bit RDTSC value:

```
  uint32_t eax, edx;
  asm __volatile__ (
    "rdtsc" "\n\t"
    : "=a" (eax), "=d" (edx)
    :
  );
```

If you only want the low 8 bits then you can just do:

```
  y = (unsigned char)eax;
```

My guess is that this is part of some RNG function and you're just using this timer value as a seed, in which case you might as well use something more portable that doesn't require inline asm.

Comment: Byte rnd[128];
        for (int i = 0; i< 128; i+=4) {
            *(unsigned long*)(&rnd[i]) = myFunction();
        }

that's how it is called, the thing is I don't even know what that all actually does, that's probably the main problem - I would otherwise be very happy not to use any inline asm.